# Handling a tap of UIImage inside of UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, uikit, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` which is called `ProfileHeaderView`. It does contain `UIImageView` called `userImage`. How can I access this `userImage` for adding a tap gesture.
Here's the piece of code for my header:

```
class ProfileHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    
    // MARK: - Subviews
    
    private var statusText: String = ""
    
    lazy var userImage: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: me.login))
                
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 45
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
                
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        return imageView
    }()
...
}
```

And here's the code I'm using inside a `UIViewController`:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if section == 0 {
            let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "ProfileHeaderView")
            view?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            
            
            let tapPicture = UITapGestureRecognizer(
                target: self,
                action: #selector(didTapPicture)
            )
            
            tapPicture = 1
            view?.userImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapPicture)
            return view
        }
        return nil
    }
```

I do get the following error: `Value of type 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView' has no member 'userImage'`. Why? I was thinking I added userImage to my header. But turns out adding it to my custom header is not enough. Is there any workaround or solution to add `tapGesture` to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView` returns `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` which does not have a `userImage` property, hence the error.

All you need is to cast the result of `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView` to `ProfileHeaderView`.

```
if let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "ProfileHeaderView") as? ProfileHeaderView {
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    let tapPicture = UITapGestureRecognizer(
        target: self,
        action: #selector(didTapPicture)
    )
    
    tapPicture = 1
    view.userImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapPicture)
    return view
}
```

One issue with this is that you will end up adding more and more gesture recognizers to the header as the user scrolls.

A better overall solution is to setup the gesture in the custom header class and define either a delegate or a callback property. Then when the custom header handles the tap, it can call the delegate or callback so the view controller can act as needed.

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot! Could you also give an example of how to handle the tap inside ProfileHeaderView and then trigger an action in UIViewController? I'm not sure I know how to delegate it from there